# Method to merge SPFile into Existing SPFile

Tags: file, sharepoint, merge

My problem is that I will have 1..n files to merge into a single file.  I have a target SPFile on the Sharepoint Server.  I have written a method based on web sites about OpenXML and it runs without errors but ends up blank when I review it.

Here is the Method

```
    private void InsertSPFileInto(SPFile target, SPFile source, int index)
    {
        Stream targetStream = target.OpenBinaryStream();
        using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetStream, true))
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + index.ToString();
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk =
                mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, 
                    altChunkId);
            Stream sourceStream = source.OpenBinaryStream();
            chunk.FeedData(sourceStream);
            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
            mainPart.Document
                .Body
                .InsertAfter(altChunk,mainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
    }
```

Again it just returns a blank document, but it doesn't corrupt it either.

Thanks.

Tim Daniels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it I found the problem I need to add the follow three lines to the method after the line "maindocument.Documents.Save()"

```
targetDoc.Close();
targetStream.Flush();
target.SaveBinary(targetStream);
```